# chrome.history.search – ignore mobile browsing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a Chrome plugin that tracks users' browsing history, but I'd like to ignore any mobile browsing, keeping only the logs that occurred on a signed-in desktop browser.

I'm also confused about whether the extension code itself runs on signed-in mobile browsers – my event script (using `chrome.alarms`) occasionally sends browsing logs to a server, and I can see logs being sent even when my laptop is closed, but they usually correspond to when I'm using Chrome on my iPhone.

I can't find any information on either of these issues Chrome's developer portal.

Comment: Presumably, you use `chrome.history`?

Comment: Yes. I've now verified that mobile browsing is not included anyway, so this is no longer a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm also confused about whether the extension code itself runs on signed-in mobile browsers

Well, for one, mobile Chrome does not support extensions; as such, there is no such risks.

However, an extension published on Chrome Web Store will, by default, replicate itself upon installation to other Chrome profiles that are signed into the same account as part of Chrome Sync. The only way to prevent it is to disable extension sync for the profile, which also makes `chrome.storage.sync` to stop replicating.

So your "unexpected" logs may come from another desktop Chrome that's signed into the same account - assuming the extension is actually published in CWS.

Comment: Thanks. I did indeed recently publish it on CWS. But I can see no other desktops/laptops on my list of signed in devices on https://security.google.com/settings/security/activity?pli=1. This is really puzzling.. Something to do with the laptop being asleep and not actually closed? Or maybe a delayed response from the server.. Will keep digging. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Perhaps someone else has it installed? How do you distinguish between users?

Comment: – each user is given a unique ID, so I know for sure the logs coming through are mine. I've also published privately for the time being and haven't shared the link anywhere. Phantom event pages :)